# PDO Select statement SQL into MySQL producing no data

Tags: mysql, sql, json, pdo

I'm finding SQL query that works in phpadmin and command line and other SQL tools is producing blank output under PDO (PHP).

The connection script and variable binding are working. I receive 200 OK but output is

```
[{"":""}]
```

It should be producing data like this.

```
Apple Inc. (aapl) 
Last price:  $103.0 
WYT fair value (npv):  $87  
Upside to WYT fv: -16%  
Valuation momentum (fwd 1 Yr):  3%  
Volatility margin of error +/-):  35%
```

Any clue to apply standard SQL syntax for PDO and any ideas what may be a problem for PDO in this instance would be really helpful.

COMMENT 20 Jan 2015 @crislar

> I fixed this by forking the original SQL written for another application to impose labels for all data being output as JSON.  I've used letters a-f which can be seen after AS

This is the revised SQL

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.inc.php");
header("Content-type: application/json");

$code_wyt = $_POST['code_wyt'];

$sth = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT
    CONCAT(sc.CoName, ' (', sc.code_wyt, ')') AS 'a',
IF (
    sc.currency_shares = '£',
    CONCAT(
        'Last price:  ',
        FORMAT(
            @price2 := (
                SELECT
                    price_close
                FROM
                    stock_prices_daily
                WHERE
                    code_wyt = :code_wyt
                ORDER BY
                    date DESC
                LIMIT 1
            ),
            0
        ),
        'p'
    ),
    CONCAT(
        'Last price:  ',
        sc.currency_shares,
        FORMAT(
            @price2 := (
                SELECT
                    price_close
                FROM
                    stock_prices_daily
                WHERE
                    code_wyt = :code_wyt
                ORDER BY
                    date DESC
                LIMIT 1
            ),
            1
        )
    )
) AS 'b',
IF (
    sc.currency_shares = '£',
    CONCAT(
        'WYT fair value (npv):  ',
        FORMAT(
            @price3 := (
                SELECT
                    npv_adj
                FROM
                    companies_monthly
                WHERE
                    code_wyt = :code_wyt
                AND date_monthly >= CURDATE()
                AND MONTH (date_monthly) = MONTH (CURDATE())
                ORDER BY
                    date_monthly
                LIMIT 1
            ),
            0
        ),
        'p'
    ),
    CONCAT(
        'WYT fair value (npv):  ',
        sc.currency_shares,
        FORMAT(
            @price3 := (
                SELECT
                    npv_adj
                FROM
                    companies_monthly
                WHERE
                    code_wyt = :code_wyt
                AND date_monthly >= CURDATE()
                AND MONTH (date_monthly) = MONTH (CURDATE())
                ORDER BY
                    date_monthly
                LIMIT 1
            ),
            0
        )
    )
) AS 'c',
 CONCAT(
    'Upside to WYT fv: ',
    ROUND(((@price3 /@price2) - 1) * 100, 0),
    '%'
) AS 'd',
 (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            'Valuation momentum (fwd 1 Yr):  ',
            ROUND((a.npv_adj / b.npv_adj - 1) * 100, 0),
            '%'
        )
    FROM
        companies_monthly a,
        companies_monthly b
    WHERE
        a.code_wyt = b.code_wyt
    AND a.code_wyt = :code_wyt
    AND b.date_monthly >= CURDATE()
    AND a.date_monthly >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    ORDER BY
        a.date_monthly,
        b.date_monthly
    LIMIT 1
) AS 'e',
 (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            'Volatility margin of error +/-):  ',
            FORMAT(
                margin_of_error_valuation * 100,
                0
            ),
            '%'
        )
    FROM
        MoE_valuation
    WHERE
        code_wyt = :code_wyt
    AND sample_period_yrs = '10'
    LIMIT 1
) AS 'f',   
 'null',
 'null',
 'null',
 'null'
FROM
    stock_codes sc,
    stock_prices_daily spd
WHERE
    sc.code_wyt = spd.code_wyt
AND sc.code_wyt = :code_wyt
ORDER BY
    spd.date
LIMIT 1");
$sth->bindParam(':code_wyt', $code_wyt, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
$result=$sth->fetchALL(PDO::§);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

cheers!

C

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this as stated above in the revised code in the original post. 
The issue was the original sql query was written to output blank lines in Excel from data held in MySQL.

JSON encoding in PDO seems to ignore data if it does not have a label.

My fix was to add labels in this case using alphabetic letters a-f so the JSON parser gets the data and outputs it as JSON.

The original SQL output three other blank lines at the end which I don't need so I've used NULL to label these. I may well change this to delete them as they are not needed in a final production version.

Thanks to Ahmed who responded with some interesting ideas and code snippets which I'll definitely keep in mind.  It's very tough looking through other people's code so loads of kudos to those who give it a go.

C

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your script to have unique placeholder names `:code_wyt1`, `:code_wyt2`, `:code_wyt3` and so forth ...

Then bind for Each paramater keeping the same value:

```
$sth->bindParam(':code_wyt1', $code_wyt, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->bindParam(':code_wyt2', $code_wyt, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->bindParam(':code_wyt3', $code_wyt, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
```

then it should work, the possible reason that you didn't see an error is that you set error mode at the end of the query I suggest you to do it along with the connection otherwise it is too late.

Note it is possible to make it work with `PDO emulation enabled`.
Other suggestion is to move your query to a stored procedure, not only it will reduce the amount of code, it will also help you maintain your query without touching your PHP script.

---

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
header("Content-type: application/json");
$result = array();
if(isset($_POST['code_wyt'])){
    $code_wyt = $_POST['code_wyt'];
    $dbh = new PDO('xxxxxxx');
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    if($sth = $dbh->prepare ("...")){
        $sth->bindParam(':code_wyt1', $code_wyt, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $sth->bindParam(':code_wyt2', $code_wyt, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $sth->bindParam(':code_wyt3', $code_wyt, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        ....
        if($sth->execute()){
            $result=$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }else{
            $result = array('error'=>'failed to execute');      
        }

    }else{
        $result = array('error'=>'failed to prepare');
    }
}else{
    $result = array('error'=>'missing code');
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate you taking the time to comment. Unfortunately adding unique placeholder id's doesn't produce anymore data than with just one.  I'll take another look at stored procedures but what I really don't want to do is edit SQL scripts beyond replacing variable place holders. I have nearly 90 SQL scripts to repurpose with PHP  (which I didn't write). So I am keen to not play with them if possible.

Comment: @crislar my advice is to get the errors to print fisrt, this should be your first attempt. If you dont have errors, you are one cluless man

Comment: Great advice. BUT >.. There are no errors. the db connects properly (I have all the connection error handling in the connection script itself). For the query script above I get 200 OK status after running the query.  The issue is that I get no data when I run the query through PDO. But I do get data if I run it elsewhere such as in phpadmin or command line.  I also have another script with only one placeholder binding that is also showing exactly the same symptoms. I'm hoping some experienced PDO eyes can spot a syntax issue such as replacing "" or avoid particular calls.

Comment: @crislar I only see one syntax issue , its `fetchAll()` not `fetchALL()`. in addition to that you can check my edit for more solid coding

Comment: I realised that the queries producing blank JSON output are coding for blank lines in another application (Excel).  That is they produce spacing lines without labels or data. I've had to fork the SQL to fix for JSON.  Fix is the PDO needs labels for all data being output as JSON.  I haven't needed unique placeholders such as :wyt_code1 etc. I can just use the one :wyt_code multiple times.  I'm adding to the code above for ref. Ahmed Thank you for your helpful ideas and input C

Comment: @crislar Im glad you solved it, I knew somehow it wasnt a syntax issue. +1 for sharing the solution and good luck